# PyOpenGL camera system

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I'm confused on how the PyOpenGL camera works or how to implement it. Am I meant to rotate and move the whole world around the camera or is there a different way?

I couldn't find anything that can help me and I don't know how to translate C to python.

I just need a way to transform the camera that can help me understand how it works.

Comment: Think about this: Are you rotating an object in front of you, or are you rotating around the object? Answer: The final picture is the same. A camera that moves is the same as if is the object who moves. In other words: setting a camera in a different position/rotation is the same as translating/rotating the object. Such transformations can be achieved with 4x4 matrices.

Comment: Ok so Basically, I should make another py script called camera.py then i do all the calulcations matrices and movements there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To say it bluntly: There is no such thing as a "camera" in OpenGL (neither there is in DirectX, or Vulkan, or in any of the legacy 3D graphics APIs). The effects of a camera is understood as some parameter that contributes to the ultimate placement of geometry inside the viewport volume.

The sooner you understand that all that current GPUs do is offering massively accelerated computational resources to set the values of pixels in a 2D grid, where the region of the pixels changed are mere points, lines or triangles on a 2D plane onto which they are projected from an arbitrarily dimensioned, abstract space, the better.

You're not even moving around the world around the camera. Setting up transformations is actually errecting the stage in which "the world" will appear in the first place. Any notion of a "camera" is an abstraction created by a higher level framework, like  a third party 3D engine or your own creation.

So instead of thinking in terms of a camera, which constrains your thinking, you should think about it this way:

*What kind of transformations do I have to chain up, to give a tuple of numbers that are called "position" an actual meaning, by letting this position turn up at a certain place on the visible screen?*

You really ought to think that way, because that is what's actually happening.

Comment: I just watched a video about this person explaining how he manipualted his camera system. I know you said that you have to think about positions and transformation, but this guy moved the whole "world" and manipulated the rotations the same way as the OpenGL docs say. I don't want to copy the code I want to Understand it. Is there potentially any videos that can explain this to me.